# ASP.NET 4 Membeship schema changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've installed yesterday Visual Studio 2012 (RTM, via mytt DreamSpark account) and created a demo MVC site (using .NET 4.0 since I wish it to be supported on Azure).

I've started to investigate the project and in addition to built-in option to use external services (Facebook, Twitter, Windows Live and Google) I've found out that the entire membership schema has been changed:

[image]

The new structure contains 4 tables (the UserProfile is a first-code approch Entity Framework table).
Note that although the tables prefix is "webpages_" its a proper MVC 4 site.

I've opened the AccountModels.cs file and saw that it has been changed too:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyGuestbook.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocalPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalLogin
    {
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I would like to ask:
- Does this the new users structure (that is generated from asp_regsql.exe) or this is a template-specific structure?
- Does somebody have any documentation about the new structure and how to integrate with it?
- Does anybody know how one can migrate an "older" project (e.g. MVC 3 project) with the old structure to the new one?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some article that answer my question.

***Edit:***
*Why the sudden changes:*
The changes has been made because Microsoft has changed the default ASP.NET MVC 4 template.
The standard "Internet Application" template which gives default accounts management has been changed and now using the WebMatrix 2 helpers.
The AccountController has been totally rewritten in order to use `SimpleMembership` class which supports the third-party integration and gives us the ability to use Entity Framework code-first approach.

*Usage of old membership providers*
As long as I've read, because the `SimpleMembership` class using `ExtendedMembershipProvider` you cannot use the default universal providers and must use the built-in provider OR creating an `ExtendedMembershipProvider` custom provider.

More information can be found here:
[Implementing membership providers using the new ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC 4 template](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Cheers!

Comment: Please sum up or quote the crucial bits right here. Link rot happens, rendering link-only answers utterly useless.

Comment: The link above summarize the difference between the traditional ASP.NET scheme and the new scheme and project template that used by ASP.NET MVC 4. The answer to my questions is the article contents... There're no specific bits that answers the whole question.